# Deploy a free product from AWS Marketplace via an API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-marketplace

Is it possible to deploy a free product from the AWS Marketplace onto an AWS instance purely via API calls?

I already have a piece of Node.js code that allows me to start/stop an AWS instance but I'd like to further automate this to add a product from the marketplace.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the AMI Marketplace?  Yes you can by providing the AMI ID# when launching a new instance.

Comment: sorry for the late response - but what's the method I'm looking for?

Comment: Was your original question about the AMI marketplace?

Comment: So the question is - how (if at all) - can I programatically create an instance and add a product to that instance from the marketplace and configure that as well?

Comment: Right and my question is, by "product" and "marketplace", are you referring to the "AMI Marketplace"?

Comment: I am referring to https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace - I thought it's called the AWS Marketplace.

Comment: Well, yes it is, but it has different types of software.  For example, it has Desktop Applications which are launched via Workspaces.  Then it also has the regular AMI's, launched via EC2.  I didn't want to write an answer without clarification on exactly what it is you're looking to launch.  So, is it an AMI you wish to launch?

Comment: I see - I wasn't aware of that. It's an AMI that I'm after, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS EC2 API allows you to launch an instance and specify the AMI (Amazon Machine Image) you wish to use.  In fact, I believe it requires it, because the OS itself comes from an AMI and without specifying an AMI, it wouldn't know what OS you want.  Additionally, there are AMI's (as you've seen in the Marketplace) that include more than just the OS- applications, various environments, etc.

I'm not a Node developer, but it looks like, in Node.js, you can specify the AMI, by providing the AMI ID# in the parameters to the runInstances method.

See the below example:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html

```
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();

var params = {
  ImageId: 'ami-1624987f', // Amazon Linux AMI x86_64 EBS
  InstanceType: 't1.micro',
  MinCount: 1, MaxCount: 1
};

// Create the instance
ec2.runInstances(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) { console.log("Could not create instance", err); return; }

  var instanceId = data.Instances[0].InstanceId;
  console.log("Created instance", instanceId);

  // Add tags to the instance
  params = {Resources: [instanceId], Tags: [
    {Key: 'Name', Value: 'instanceName'}
  ]};
  ec2.createTags(params, function(err) {
    console.log("Tagging instance", err ? "failure" : "success");
  });
});
```

Note the parameters Object created with both the ImageId and InstanceType.  I would imagine both are likely required elements.  With this code, you would obviously need to hardcode the AMI ID, however you would then be able to automate the launching of new instances.

You can find more information in the Javascript API, here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html

I hope that helps!